# Find if a machine is in Active Directory by IP

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to find a way to check if a machine is in the domain (local Active Directory domain), but I only have the ip address.

Doing a reverse DNS query is not an option since not all the subnets have that zone defined.

Does anybody know of a way to do this. All that google seems to give me is hostname based.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IP data isn't stored in AD so there's not really a good way to do this. If you're using secure DNS, and have aging/scavening enabled, you could enumerate the forward lookup zone and see what's registered for that IP. You'd need to look at the refresh time on it to generate some level of confidence given it's not really going to guarantee anything if you get a match.